# How to structure URLs for language localized marketing and admin pages

Tags: language, urls, seo

So I have let's say 20 languages the *marketing pages* of the website are localized into. I am thinking of doing this...

```
mywebsite.com/en/page-1
mywebsite.com/en/page-2
mywebsite.com/zh/page-1
mywebsite.com/zh/page-2
...
```

Actually, instead of putting the *latin* script in there, I would really do this:

```
mywebsite.com/english/page-1
mywebsite.com/english/page-2
mywebsite.com/中文/页一
mywebsite.com/中文/...
```

The reason for that is it gives an SEO benefit I would think, for the native language pages.

But now we move onto the admin panel. The admin panel might *also* have these 20 languages, but should it be structured the same way? Or should it instead be like this:

```
mywebsite.com/admin/users/1/edit?lang=zh
mywebsite.com/admin/users/1/edit?lang=en
....
```

Or better yet, just store the language in `localStorage` and clean up the URL completely.

The reason we do it this way is because these pages are all hidden anyways from search engines, so there's no SEO benefit to be had. Is this the correct way to handle both situations? Or what is best?

Answer (score 2):

There is no feasible SEO benefit (unless anyone can prove it?)

There is a pain for sharing non Latin links as the link will end up containing %20%32%36 for non valid URL characters and therefore can not be read by human.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547899/which-characters-make-a-url-invalid

My native language is Russian, I study Japanese, my keyboard does not have Japanese characters, how do I alter link to see japan page?

ISO notation is great in every way, everyone use it and there is really no reason for you not to follow it:

- http://apple.com/ru
- https://www.microsoft.com/ru-ru
- https://ru.stackoverflow.com/
- [https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Языковая_локализация](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AF%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)

I have never ever seen someone to make links localized:
[https://site.com/русский/latest-article](https://site.com/%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9/latest-article) 
Looks very odd to me

storing locale in localStorage is also not good as you can not send a link to a localized page:

- I send localized link to my foreign colleague on his language
- if particular page does not contain say French translation, it is clear how to get alternatives for other languages, and they are linkable. You will have a problem otherwise.

For most of webserves it is no longer a problem to have ../en-us/... instead of ?locale=en-us
They can even transform one into another in background, so there is no need to choose less beautiful option to pass locale as query string (?locale=en)

[image]

Comment: I agree. Our company sells products all across the world and all links are simply held in English. Except for the German page, which has German localized links, as that is the birthplace of the company and users expect it to be German and not international. But that is not an issue as nearly all German characters are present in English as well. OP's case would include a lot more invalid characters, which I think would only lead to confusion across different users as well.

Comment: I don't understand this argument about "invalid" URL characters. Wikipedia uses the native scripts EVERYWHERE, and it looks nice to me. IE https://th.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E0%B8%AB%E0%B8%99%E0%B9%89%E0%B8%B2%E0%B8%AB%E0%B8%A5%E0%B8%B1%E0%B8%81

Comment: Looks like a top [Chinese website](https://new.qq.com/rain/a/20200122A095OJ00) doesn't use localized URLs...

Comment: Baidu puts them in the URL: `http://www.baidu.com/s?rsv_idx=1&wd=%E9%98%BF%E5%9D%9D%E5%B7%9E4.5%E7%BA%A7%E5%9C%B0%E9%9C%87&usm=1&ie=utf-8&rsv_cq=food%E6%98%AF%E4%BB%80%E4%B9%88%E6%84%8F%E6%80%9D%E4%B8%AD%E6%96%87&rsv_dl=0_right_fyb_pchot_20811_01&rsf=390f0462fd5ad42382be9e734b8d6541_1_15_1&rqid=b86dc60d000ce7bc` http://www.baidu.com/s?rsv_idx=1&wd=%E9%98%BF%E5%9D%9D%E5%B7%9E4.5%E7%BA%A7%E5%9C%B0%E9%9C%87&usm=1&ie=utf-8&rsv_cq=food%E6%98%AF%E4%BB%80%E4%B9%88%E6%84%8F%E6%80%9D%E4%B8%AD%E6%96%87&rsv_dl=0_right_fyb_pchot_20811_01&rsf=390f0462fd5ad42382be9e734b8d6541_1_15_1&rqid=b86dc60d000ce7bc

Comment: i've attached screenshot how localized url will look like if I try to share it

Comment: This Thai website uses it in the URL https://shopee.co.th/%E0%B8%AD%E0%B8%B2%E0%B8%AB%E0%B8%B2%E0%B8%A3%E0%B9%80%E0%B8%AA%E0%B8%A3%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%A1%E0%B9%81%E0%B8%A5%E0%B8%B0%E0%B8%9C%E0%B8%A5%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%95%E0%B8%A0%E0%B8%B1%E0%B8%93%E0%B8%91%E0%B9%8C%E0%B8%AA%E0%B8%B8%E0%B8%82%E0%B8%A0%E0%B8%B2%E0%B8%9E-cat.21732

Comment: Most have romanization or use numbers, all of which is unreadable haha

Comment: @LancePollard I (and 69% of Internet) use Google Chrome, which will escape URL and make it look like %AA%BB%CC. This only means 69% of your users will see ugly links, no more no less :) Situation may change in future, but at this point it works that way, so you have to keep it in mind to make right desicion

Comment: Got it, well my Google Chrome on mac shows the nice native script, are you on windows? Here is a korean site https://namu.wiki/w/%EB%82%98%EB%AC%B4%EC%9C%84%ED%82%A4:%EB%8F%84%EC%9B%80%EB%A7%90 and https://m.sleepmania.net/product/%EC%98%A4%EB%81%8C%EB%A6%AC%EC%98%A4-%ED%93%A8%EC%96%B4-%EC%88%98%EB%82%A9%ED%98%95-%EC%A1%B0%EB%AA%85-led-%EC%B9%A8%EB%8C%80/176/category/59/display/1/

Comment: yep i'm on Windows. Interting, so Chrome has different behavior across platforms

Comment: I mean, these numbers like [here](https://www.1in.am/2690626.html) are no less better UX than encoded URL params.